# Hibernate one-to-many mapping configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I am trying to implement one-to-many relationship with cascade loading and updating. However, my code always generates `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister` exception. Could you take a look on my attempt and suggest what am I doing wrong?

The general idea is that there is a Company class which contains set of customers. When creating new instance of customer, I add him to a company and persist everything.

Entities (only displaying relevant parts, or at least I hope so)

```
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 146243652;

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String website;
    private Set<Customer> customers;
    ... getters, setters etc

public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 864235654;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String adress;
    private String id;
    private Company company;
```

customer.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="wa2.entities.Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
        <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="NAME" name="name" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="SURNAME" name="surname" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="ADRESS" name="adress" type="java.lang.String" />

         <many-to-one name="COMPANY" class="wa2.entities.Company">
             <column name="COMPANY_ID" not-null="true"></column> 
         </many-to-one> 
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

company.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="wa2.entities.Company" table="COMPANY">
        <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="NAME" name="name" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="WEBSITE" name="website" type="java.lang.String" />

        <set name="CUSTOMERS" table="CUSTOMER" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="CUSTOMER_ID" not-null="true"></column>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="wa2.entities.Customer"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Saving customer (this worked before the implementation of one-to-many relationship so I doubt that there is anything wrong with this code):

```
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        customer.setName(name);
        String surname = req.getParameter("surname");
        customer.setSurname(surname);
        String adress = req.getParameter("adress");
        customer.setAdress(adress);

        String companyID = req.getParameter("companyId");
        Company company = repository.loadCompany(companyID);
        customer.setCompany(company);

        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        customer.setId(id);

        repository.saveCustomer(customer);
```

I hope that I did not forget any relevant part. If so, please tell me and I will post the relevant code. Thank you very much for any help!

EDIT:
Thanks for the responses. It seems that I wrote the names wrongly in capitals. I changed that and now I am getting `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: wa2.entities.Company.customers, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Comment: aren't you supposed to annotate the relevant setters (or getters) in your entity class with `@OneToMany`?....Assuming you haven't done so (in your hidden code)

Comment: Not an answer, but if you're learning Hibernate, why are you still using XML files to configure the mapping. These were fine when annotations didn't exist, 10 years ago, but we have annotations now, and Hibernate mapping is much easier and standard when using the standard JPA annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since this is an mapping exception, i guess it comes up during session factory creation, and not when saving? also, seeing the whole stacktrace could help. your exception can be caused by a mismatch of property names between mapping file and beans. see [Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042247/could-not-get-constructor-for-org-hibernate-persister-entity-singletableentitype).

in your code you have the name attribute values in

```
<many-to-one name="COMPANY" class="wa2.entities.Company">
    <column name="COMPANY_ID" not-null="true"></column> 
</many-to-one>
```

and

```
<set name="CUSTOMERS" table="CUSTOMER" fetch="select">
     <key>
        <column name="CUSTOMER_ID" not-null="true"></column>
     </key>
     <one-to-many class="wa2.entities.Customer"/>
 </set>
```

in uppercase, while the properties in your pojos are named company and customer.

Comment: This almost works - now I am getting this exception: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: wa2.entities.Company.customers, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: while working with your pojos (calling getter/setter) etc. be sure to keep the hibernate session with which the pojos are associated (loaded from/merged into) open. if you use spring you can for example easily achive this by loading and manipulating your pojos always within the boundaries of a transaction.  also, could you please mark my answer as correct, as the original problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

One principle in hibernate, that is often stated, but even more often overseen, is, that you need to keep a clean object tree, or the database will not be kept in sync properly.

I think this causes your problem: You need to keep the tree clean. But you don't: You add the customer to the company on the customer side, but you do not add the customer to the company's customer set.

In your code, you have added a vice-versa link between customer and company. I would add an inverse to the link, for this is what you want.

Second: If you start with hibernate now, really think about the annotation approach. If you inherit legacy apps, stay with the XML, but if you start out fresh ...