# JPA Predicate to get parent entity based on child entity count

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have following entity structure:

```
@Entity
class ParentClass {
  @Id
  int id;
  @ManyToMany
  List<ChildClass> childAttribute;
}

@Entity
public class ChildClass {    
  @Id
  int id;    
}
```

I want to write a predicate to fetch the Parent entities, where the size of attribute named childAttribute is "Zero".
Thanks.

Comment: use two dimensional way mapping..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316485/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-configuration

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ParentClass> cq = cb.createQuery(ParentClass.class);
Root<ParentClass> root = cq.from(ParentClass.class);
cq.select(root)
    .where(cb.isEmpty(root.get("childAttribute")));

TypedQuery<ParentClass> query = em.createQuery(cq);
List<ParentClass> result = query.getResultList();
```

Equivalent JPQL query is:

```
SELECT p FROM ParentClass p where p.childAttribute IS EMPTY
```

For further details please refer to [JPQL syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage005.htm#BNBUF).