# javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using Spring along with Hibernate. I understand that I am using an outdated setup and should ideally switch to Spring Boot and Maven. However this assignment requires me to proceed with the current setup only.

Error log:
Exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Root Cause:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Below are my relevant files:

/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="springstudent" />
        <property name="password" value="springstudent" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  
    
    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>  
</beans>
```

/src/main/java/com/luv2code/springdemo/controller/CustomerController.java:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.dao.CustomerDAO;
import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    
    //inject the customer dao into this controller 
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO; 
    
    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model theModel) {
        
        //get the customers from the dao 
        List<Customer> theCustomers = customerDAO.getCustomers(); 
        
        //add the customers to the model 
        theModel.addAttribute("customers", theCustomers); 
        
        return "list-customers"; 
    }
}
```

/src/main/java/com/luv2code/springdemo/dao/CustomerDAO.java:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;


public interface CustomerDAO {

    public List<Customer> getCustomers(); 
    
}
```

/src/main/java/com/luv2code/springdemo/dao/CustomerDAOImpl.java:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    //need to inject the session factory 
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory; 
    
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        
        //get the current hibernate session 
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
        
        //create a query 
        Query<Customer> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class); 
        
        //execute query and result list 
        List<Customer> customers = theQuery.getResultList(); 
        
        //return the results 
        return customers;
    }

}
```

/src/main/java/com/luv2code/testdb/TestDbServlet.java:

```
package com.luv2code.testdb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*; 

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestDbServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TestDbServlet")
public class TestDbServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        //setup connection variables 
        String user = "springstudent"; 
        String pass = "springstudent"; 
        String jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC"; 
        String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        
        //get connection to database 
        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
            out.println("Connecting to database: " + jdbcUrl); 
            Class.forName(driver); 
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass); 
            out.println("Success!"); 
            myConn.close();   
        }
        catch(Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace(); 
            throw new ServletException(exc); 
        }
    }

}
```

List of jar files I am using for this project:

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar                                 spring-instrument-5.3.9.jar
c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar                                spring-instrument-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
classmate-1.3.0.jar                             spring-instrument-5.3.9-sources.jar
commons-logging-1.2.1.1.jar                     spring-jcl-5.3.9.jar
dom4j-2.1.1.jar                                 spring-jcl-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
hibernate-c3p0-5.2.18.Final.jar                 spring-jcl-5.3.9-sources.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar   spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.18.Final.jar                 spring-jdbc-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar           spring-jdbc-5.3.9-sources.jar
jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar                          spring-jms-5.3.9.jar
javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar                         spring-jms-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar                spring-jms-5.3.9-sources.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar            spring-messaging-5.3.9.jar
javax.xml.bind.jar                              spring-messaging-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar                   spring-messaging-5.3.9-sources.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar  spring-orm-5.3.9.jar
mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar                 spring-orm-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar                 spring-orm-5.3.9-sources.jar
spring-aop-5.3.9.jar                            spring-oxm-5.3.9.jar
spring-aop-5.3.9-javadoc.jar                    spring-oxm-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
spring-aop-5.3.9-sources.jar                    spring-oxm-5.3.9-sources.jar
spring-aspects-5.3.9.jar                        spring-r2dbc-5.3.9.jar
spring-aspects-5.3.9-javadoc.jar                spring-r2dbc-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
spring-aspects-5.3.9-sources.jar                spring-r2dbc-5.3.9-sources.jar
spring-beans-5.3.9.jar                          spring-test-5.3.9.jar
spring-beans-5.3.9-javadoc.jar                  spring-test-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
spring-beans-5.3.9-sources.jar                  spring-test-5.3.9-sources.jar
spring-context-5.3.9.jar                        spring-tx-5.3.9.jar
spring-context-5.3.9-javadoc.jar                spring-tx-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
spring-context-5.3.9-sources.jar                spring-tx-5.3.9-sources.jar
spring-context-indexer-5.3.9.jar                spring-web-5.3.9.jar
spring-context-indexer-5.3.9-javadoc.jar        spring-web-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
spring-context-indexer-5.3.9-sources.jar        spring-web-5.3.9-sources.jar
spring-context-support-5.3.9.jar                spring-webflux-5.3.9.jar
spring-context-support-5.3.9-javadoc.jar        spring-webflux-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
spring-context-support-5.3.9-sources.jar        spring-webflux-5.3.9-sources.jar
spring-core-5.3.9.jar                           spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar
spring-core-5.3.9-javadoc.jar                   spring-webmvc-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
spring-core-5.3.9-sources.jar                   spring-webmvc-5.3.9-sources.jar
spring-expression-5.3.9.jar                     spring-websocket-5.3.9.jar
spring-expression-5.3.9-javadoc.jar             spring-websocket-5.3.9-javadoc.jar
spring-expression-5.3.9-sources.jar             spring-websocket-5.3.9-sources.jar
```

I am checked and rechecked everything multiple times and cannot seem to get to a solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042247/could-not-get-constructor-for-org-hibernate-persister-entity-singletableentitype update javaassist to 3.28.0-GA

Comment: @Andreas I checked, it's not the same